# Substituting Chicken Breast for Chicken Legs in Korma

Tags: substitutions, chicken, indian-cuisine

I am looking at Madhur Jaffrey's Chicken Korma recipe as given at http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/creamychickenkormawi_90196; however I only have chicken breasts. In what manner should I modify the final simmering process or the spice/flavor balance or make up for this discrepancy?

Comment: The recipe calls for chicken parts, and specifically says to cut breasts in half.  What are you asking?

Comment: Only thing I would worry about is not to cook the breast for too long, otherwise it will be dry and nobody likes dry chicken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a recipe calls for assorted chicken parts, you can swap out all white meat or all dark meat to your liking safely. I do it fairly often, depending what cut is on sale or what I have lying around in my freezer. It shouldn't change much.

Answer (score 0):

Logically speaking cooking chicken legs means less flesh which requires less time than cooking chicken breast which is whole flesh.

for 1 kg of chicken legs = 250 gms of chicken(in India,I don't know the chicken size in your country) so modify everything in propotion.

Answer (score 0):

Chicken hind quarters have a much larger proportion of connective tissue which gives stews and braises a more unctuous flavor after those tissues have been rendered. Chicken breast, on the other hand, while much lower in fat, gives less flavor in stews.

3lb of chicken meat about what one would expect to get when stripping all the meat off of a roaster, so I assume this recipe intended to have some thigh or drum meat.

I like a lot of meat flavor in my stews. If I were making this stew with chicken breast, I would replace some or all of the water called for in the recipe with chicken stock to reintroduce those flavors.